# Hierarchical panels vs hardcoded margins performance

Tags: wpf, panel

When designing WPF applications, is it better in terms of performance to use multiple nested panels (as they are designed to be used) or hard code the margin of most of the controls and put them in one panel such as grid?
[image: Sample UI]
For example to design the above, we can write:

```
<StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="اطلاعات خود را وارد نمایید:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="نام: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCFirstName" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="نام خانوادگی: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCLastName" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="تلفن منزل: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCHomeNumber" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="تلفن همراه: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCMobileNumber" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="شرکت: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCCompany" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="سمت: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="تلفن کاری: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCWorkNumber" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                                <TextBlock Text="وب سایت: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbVCWebSite" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                        <TextBlock Text="ایمیل شخصی: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbVCPersonalEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                        <TextBlock Text="ایمیل کاری: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbVCWorkEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="5, 3">
                        <TextBlock Text="آدرس: " VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbVCAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
```

Or we can declare all of them in one grid and give them margins.
[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx) says "In many cases, a Grid element can be used instead of nested panels due to its flexibility as a layout container. This can increase performance in your application by keeping unnecessary elements out of the tree." but it seems odd to me!

Which of the above implementations is better for run time rendering performance and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is that you shouldn't nest elements inside different panels, if performance is necessary - flattening out will work usually nicely.

The `Margin` one will be faster, as it's very easy to calculate the final position of the elements. `DockPanel` one will need to calculate its own position, plus it's children, which makes it more expensive.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's unfortunate since it's not maintainable. If we want to add one other field in the middle, we will have to modify all those margins.

Comment: @SepehrM, yes it's true. However my real life experience has shown that you can usually relax and create your things in such way that they are maintainable without worrying about the performance - eg go with the `DockPanel` route. It's true that if you have very complex UI that is deep(eg has many panels nested inside), it will improve the performance if you flatten out everything, and get rid of panels you don't  need..

Comment: That's a really good news. Our control templates are very complex and we have done our best to simplify their structure. But in designing pages and windows, I think maintainability is more important. How can I test the rendering speed myself?

Comment: @SepehrM: this can get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (WPF Performance suite)

Comment: Can I use that tool for .NET 4.0 on Windows 8.1 dev machine?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with defined Margin, is that when you try to resize the Window your controls will appear **cropped** as it has to make space for the margins. This is the same when you define lengths and widths for controls. To make it more resolution independent nesting would be a better option, through even this may not provide better results in very low resolutions.

Comment: True. How about performance? System resources consumption and the time it takes to fully render.

Comment: Some panels can be easily omitted. For example, stack panels don't provide much flexibility when the content is static. In most scenarios you can implement the same behavior without nested stack panels.

Comment: Panels do have some performance implications, but this would be varied for each type of panel.